# df.query while using pandas in python produces empty results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning how to manipulate data using pandas in python. I got the following script:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table( "t.txt" )    #read in the file
df.columns = [x.strip() for x in df.columns]   #strip spaces in headers
df = df.query('TLD == ".biz"')     #select the rows where TLD == ".biz"
df.to_csv('t.txt', sep='\t')  #write the output to a tab-separated file
```

but the output file has no records, headers only. When I check using

```
print.df
```

prior to the selection, the output is:

```
             TLD  Length                                              Words  \
0       .biz           5                                                ...   
1       .biz           4                                                ...   
2       .biz           5                                                ...   
3       .biz           5                                                ...   
4       .biz           3                                                ...   
5       .biz           3                                                ...   
6       .biz           6                                                ...
```

So I know the column TLD has rows with the .biz values. I also tried :

```
>>> print(df.loc[df['TLD'] == '.biz'])
```

but the results is

```
Empty DataFrame
```

With list of my columns

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems some whitespaces are there, so need remove them by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
print(df.loc[df['TLD'].str.strip() == '.biz'])
```

---

```
df['TLD'] = df['TLD'].str.strip()
df = df.query('TLD == ".biz"')
```

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity - how did you recognized white spaces beign there? To my untrained eye it all look good

Comment: because you remove whitespaces in columns, so I think in data are too ;)

Comment: and maybe simplier for remove whitespaces in columns is `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`